# Systemd Weekly Timer

Tags: systemd

I would like to set up a systemd timer that runs every 5 minutes between the hours of 9 AM - 5 PM only from Monday to Friday. I have searched online and I have seen close scenarios but not this one and I am not completely sure about the syntax.

I tried this but it still doesn't seem to work:

```
Mon...Fri *-*-* 9-17/*:05:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is explained in the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.time.html):

> Values may be suffixed with "/" and a repetition value, which
> indicates that the value itself and the value plus all multiples of
> the repetition value are matched

In your case the repetition value is 5 minutes so the `/` has to come after the minutes component:

```
OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-* 09..16:0/5
```

Comment: @SoftwareInfo Did you `daemon-reload` systemd after editing the timer? The error clearly uses what you have in the question and not what's in the answer.

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks so very much. I just learned about systemd-analyze calendar and this has been a big help as well.